# What is the period of this expression?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics

I already know that this expression is periodic, but what I don't know is what is the period.  In other words what values of $n$ will give me zeros for this:
$$  \Sigma_{i=1}^n\sin(6\Sigma_{x=1}^i x^2-x-1)  $$

Comment: This is a bit unmotivated. It doesn't look very periodic and plots up to n=65536 don't look very periodic. Why do you think it is? Also note that the inner summation can be performed analytically.

Comment: Doesn't look periodic up to $10^8$ either. Looks like Brownian motion.

Answer (score 3):

Let me use $j$ rather than $i$ for the summation variable, because I need $i$ for $\sqrt{-1}$.  So you're looking at $$\eqalign{\sum_{j=1}^n \sin(2 j^3 - 8 j) &= \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\exp((2 j^3 - 8 j)i) - \exp(-(2 j^3 - 8 j)i)}{2i}\cr  &=  i R_n(e^i)\cr}$$
where $R_n(z)$ is a non-constant (if $n \ge 1$) rational function with integer coefficients.  But $\exp(i)$ is transcendental by [Lindemann's theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lindemann_theorem), so
the result will never be $0$ for $n \ge 1$.  In fact the only 
members of this sequence that are equal are for $n=1$ and $n=2$
(as $2 \cdot 2^3 - 8 \cdot 2 = 0$).

... or did you want to use degrees rather than radians?